# onActivityResult resultCode is giving vise versa result

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, camera

I am using the Default android Image Capture intent and I have a Problem. This is my Code

```
 fun onCameraClick(): View.OnClickListener {
        return View.OnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

            if (intent.resolveActivity(dialog.context.packageManager) != null) {
                var photoFile: File? = null

                try {
                    photoFile = dialog.context.createImageFile()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Timber.e(e)
                }

                photoFile?.let {
                    val photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                            dialog.context,
                            "${dialog.context.packageName}.fileprovider",
                            it
                    )
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
                    generalBottomSheetDialogFragment?.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
                }
            }
        }
    }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        when (requestCode) {
            CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE -> {

                when {
                    requestCode == -1 -> {

                    }
                    requestCode == RESULT_CODE_OK -> {

                    }
                    else -> {

                    }
                }

            }
            PDF_REQUEST_CODE ->
                data?.also {
                    generalResponse.setElement(it)
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
        }


    }
```

My problem is when I Successfully take a picture the resultCode would be -1 and when I press back from the camera I get the RESULT_CODE_OK. Can anyone help me to see why is this happening? What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause:** Because your code is not correct

**Solution:** Change your code

From

```
when {
    requestCode == -1 -> {

    }
    requestCode == RESULT_CODE_OK -> {

    }
    else -> {

    }
}
```

To

```
when {
    resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK -> {

    }
    resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED -> {

    }
    else -> {

    }
}
```